# Getting `No such file or directory` when executing any terminal command (caused by VMware Fusion)

Tags: macos, path, vmware, fusion, vmware-fusion

I am using macOS High Sierra and I am getting the following error when trying to install a script:

```
 sh: Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Users/<name>/.rvm/bin: No such file or directory
```

Apparently has something to do either with `rvm` or `Fusion.app`, which I don't have that app, what I have is `VMWare Fusion.app`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

VMWare changes your `$PATH` variable, but it does not do in `.profile`, or `/etc/profile`, neither the globals or locals `bashrc` or `zshrc` files.

It has its own file inside `/etc/paths.d`. The file is called `com.vmware.fusion.public`.

You **need sudo** rights to change the file:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/paths.d/com.vmware.fusion.public
```

The file is `readonly` and it has as content:

```
/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public
```

Notice there **are not** quotes around it, and the **space character** is not escaped. You need to add a `\` after the `VMWare` and before the white space.

Final result:

```
/Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Public
```

Quit `vim` with `:x!`.

Open a new terminal window and run your command again, you should not have that error anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately newer versions of VMware Fusion now rewrite this value every time it is launched. It's quite annoying. The only solution right now is to rename the application itself to "VMWare-Fusion.app" or "VMWareFusion.app" (for example)

Comment: Should someone let them know so that this doe not come back with every update?...

Comment: I just checked with the VMware Fusion team and posted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71109863/167362) below.

Answer (score 1):

With VMware Fusion rewriting `/etc/paths.d/com.vmware.fusion.public` on launch;

Adding this PATH find and replace line to my .bash_profile seems to be working:

`export PATH=${PATH//VMware\ F/VMware\\ F}`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because some shell script (in this case perhaps `rvm`) is not following best practices, specifically:

> [Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting](http://Double%20quote%20to%20prevent%20globbing%20and%20word%20splitting)
> https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086

Changing `/etc/paths.d/com.vmware.fusion.public` as suggested in other answers could break all other places where this variable is wrapped in double quotes.